# Web-scraping in Python how parse html?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I try scraping site in ajax page. I'm just learning python. Sorry if that is an easy question.

Using selenium to load a page and download a piece of code in html.
They work perfectly as I want. 
But I have a problem how to parse these data.

I would like the data to look like this (It may be writing this data to a variable because then I want to transfer it to the mysql database.):

```
Custom ID:
Name:
Ticket NO:
Rate:
Win:
```

Data location in html code::

```html
<li class="message">
    <div customid="CUSTOM ID">
        <span class="name nc-mark-user">NAME</span>
        <p>
            <span><img src="https://cht.sts.pl/assets/img/accepted.svg" width="15" height="15"> <span class="nc-ticket" onclick="serchTicketHandler('TICKET NO')">RATE / WIN zł</span></span>
        </p>
    </div>
</li>
```

My code in python:

```python
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from xml.dom import minidom


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(
            ("C:/Users/backu/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"),
            chrome_options=options)

browser.get("https://www.sts.pl/pl/oferta/zaklady-live/")
time.sleep(1)
element = browser.find_element_by_class_name("nc-message-holder")

source = element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(source)

browser.close()
```

I don't know how to read this code now to extract the data I want.

Thank you so much for all the answers.

Comment: You can use beautifulsoup to parse and traverse the HTML. You've already imported it, so you're halfway there. http://www.compjour.org/warmups/govt-text-releases/intro-to-bs4-lxml-parsing-wh-press-briefings/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(
        ("C:/Users/backu/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"),
        chrome_options=options)

browser.get("https://www.sts.pl/pl/oferta/zaklady-live/")
sleep(1)
source = browser.page_source # Get the entire page source from the browser
if browser is not None :browser.close() # No need for the browser so close it 
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')
try:
    Tags = soup.select('ul.nc-message-holder li.message') # get the elements using css selectors    
    for tag in Tags: # loop through them 
        customerId = tag.find('div').get('customid')
        name       = tag.find('div').find('span').text
        #<span class="nc-ticket" onclick="serchTicketHandler('223461999015343335')">8.00 / 51.04 zł</span>
        ticketTag  = tag.select('span.nc-ticket')
        if ticketTag : 
            ticketNum = ticketTag[0].get('onclick').replace("serchTicketHandler('","").replace("')","")
            rate_Win  = ticketTag[0].text
            if '/' in rate_Win:
                rate_Win = rate_Win.split('/')
                rate      = rate_Win[0].strip()
                win       = rate_Win[1].strip()
            else:
                rate = rate_Win
                win  = ''

            print('\n\ncustomerId ==>',customerId)
            print('name ==>',name)
            print('ticketNum ==>',ticketNum)
            print('rate ==>',rate)
            print('win ==>',win)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Output:

```
customerId ==> c46654fa66765ae11bb34d7d99cf0a77
name ==> Wojciech W
ticketNum ==> 223461999016744267
rate ==> 100.00
win ==> 1340.24 zł


customerId ==> 7b071de240b730ad42cee50711dd8c72
name ==> Grzegorz P
ticketNum ==> 223461988025841282
rate ==> 15.94
win ==> 46.28 zł


customerId ==> 244950ab8485b7180c177a2b7b19b0ae
name ==> Michał J
ticketNum ==> 313441988030838257
rate ==> 12.00
win ==> 73967.98 zł


customerId ==> 9223e1c2f87afb02e6c704acb53308da
name ==> Piotr G
ticketNum ==> 313431999017162038
rate ==> 2.00
win ==> 430.40 zł


customerId ==> 4a8e2695fe71a084f69167ac987c7013
name ==> Dawid B
ticketNum ==> 313461988013246357
rate ==> 10.00
win ==> 1569.30 zł


customerId ==> 6b882a5ef93e0c3e52b81bbee0ba52af
name ==> Adrian P
ticketNum ==> 313441988034262951
rate ==> 2.00
win ==> 451268.63 zł


customerId ==> abd34ea0c7a9b0e07a53a78324cb7e0a
name ==> Michał D
ticketNum ==> 223461999013746135
rate ==> 10.00
win ==> 27.72 zł


customerId ==> bed4fc0ea1f21a7a9b1c6762d2302d09
name ==> Rafał Ż
ticketNum ==> 223461988021146803
rate ==> 607.40
win ==> 2150.26 zł
```